# Count how many columns match conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table `[Table]` with 3 columns `[Column1]`, `[Column2]` and `[Column3]`.

My condition is:

```
WHERE [Column1] LIKE '%q%' OR [Column2] LIKE '%q%' OR [Column3] LIKE '%q%'
```

It works but I'd like to order results by the number of match.

For example

```
C1 - C2 - C3 
q - q - q
q - a - q
q - a - a
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to order by the number of matched columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `ORDER BY` clause on your query:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Column1] LIKE '%q%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
          CASE WHEN [Column2] LIKE '%q%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
          CASE WHEN [Column3] LIKE '%q%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] FROM [Table]
WHERE [Column1] LIKE '%q%' OR [Column2] LIKE '%q%' OR [Column3] LIKE '%q%'
ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN [Column1] LIKE '%q%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN [Column2] LIKE '%q%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN [Column3] LIKE '%q%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a fourth column, similar to this:

```
SELECT [Col1],[Col2],[Col3], 
   CAST([Col1] LIKE '%q%' AS SMALLINT) + CAST([Col2] LIKE '%q%' AS SMALLINT) +
   CAST([Col3] LIKE '%q%' AS SMALLINT) AS Strength
....
ORDER BY Strength
```

Since I don't know which database you're using, you may need to consult the documentation to see how to cast from a boolean value to an integer.

Itay